# Универсальный путь к папке Temp

Tags: windows, файловая-система

На win10 существует путь к папке temp в виде: C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp. Как получить универсальный тег в строке поиска для Current user-a, что бы пропустить USERNAME?

Comment: Зачем так сложно, проще взять значение  переменной `TEMP` из environment винды.

Comment: %TEMP% - не оно? Или вам в программе?

Comment: Нужен конкретный лог файл в папке Temp, который бы подходил под любого, запустившего приложение

Comment: @Rifter вам для приложения или для адресной строки в проводнике, попробую спросить еще раз.

Comment: @Владимир Мартьянов для приложения

Answer (score 1):

`GetTempPath()` служит для получения пути к временному каталогу, попробуйте ее.

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно